# NestJS localhost refused to connect

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I have a NestJS app that has been running for years and has been in production as well.

I need to add some features, the app started smoothly on the local machine, but refused the connection on the browser.

@Brandon

Here is main.ts

```
import 'dotenv/config';
let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
import * as rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';


appInsights.setup(process.env.azureAppInsight).start();

appInsights.defaultClient.addTelemetryProcessor((envelope, context) => {
  const httpRequest = context['http.ServerRequest'];
  const baseData = envelope.data.baseData;
  if (httpRequest && appInsights.Contracts.domainSupportsProperties(baseData)) {
    if (httpRequest.method === 'POST') {
      baseData.properties['bodyRequest'] = JSON.stringify(httpRequest.body);
    } else {

    }
  }
  return true;
});

const port = process.env.PORT;

async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  //logger: ['log', 'error', 'warn', 'debug', 'verbose']
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    const options = new DocumentBuilder().addBearerAuth()
      .setTitle('Sure')
      .setDescription('')
      .setVersion('1.0')
      .addTag('Secured')
      .build();

    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
    SwaggerModule.setup('', app, document);
  }

  app.enableCors();
  app.use(helmet());

  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log('info', `Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share some more information? Any logs in the console? What does your `main.ts` file look like

Comment: @Brandon I have updated with the main.ts

Comment: Make sure that the browser is not behind the proxy.

Comment: @techstack hmm is it just the root url `/` that shows an error? Are you able to hit any of the endpoints in Postman? May just be an issue with the swagger docs.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after downgrading from v17 to v14.